# nginx Ingress controller on Kubernetes not able to access

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I installed nginx ingress controller on AKS cluster.But not able to access ingress endpoints that are exposed by our app.As per the initial analysis we see that ingress endpoints have been assigned external IP of one of the node where as ingress controller service has different IP.

What I am doing wrong ?

```
$kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep ingress
kube-system  ingress-nginx-58ftggg-4xc56   1/1 Running

$kubectl get svc
kubernetes  CLUSTERIP  172.16.0.1    none(ExternalIP)  443/TCP

$kubectl get ingress
vault-ingress-documentation 10.145.13.456

$kubectl describe ingress vault-ingress-documentation
Name:vault-ingress-documentation
Namespace:corebanking
Address:10.145.13.456
Default backend:default-http-backend:80 (<error:default-http-backend:80 not found)

$kubectl get services -n kube-system | grep ingress
ingress-nginx Loadbalancer 172.16.160.33 10.145.13.456 80:30389/TCP,443:31812/TCP
```

Comment: can you post the `kubectl get ingress` and describe the same ingress, if its pointing to the right service?

Comment: @Adiii : Updated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have created deployment so it will create **replica sets** and **pods** for the particular nodes and we can see the pods are up and running like below:

```
Kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

[image]

I have created the **deployment for the service file** it will access inside of the cluster IP:

```
Kubectl create -f service.yaml
```

[image]

To expose the external IP of the application, I created the ingress rules using **`Ingress.yaml`** file.
I have added the annotation class for the **`ingress.yaml`** file like below:

```yaml
annotations:  
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

***Here ingress rules will be created with empty address like below:***

[image]

When I try to access the application, I am not able to access. To access the application, add **loadBalancer IP** with **Domain name** in `/etc/host` path.

[image]

*Now I am able to connect the application with service IP, but I am not able to expose to the external IP.*

**To expose to the external IP, I added annotation class like below:**

```yaml
annotations:  
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx  
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

After that I have applied the changes in the **`ingressrules.yaml`** file:

```yaml
kubectl replace –force -f ingress_rules.yaml  
OR  
Kubectl create -f ingress_rules.yaml
```

[image]

***Now I am able to see the address of the IP, by using this I am able to access the application.***